# Change the order of elements in vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector with elements in a certain row, but now I want to change the order of these elements. How can I do this with only one line of code?

```
# 1.create queue

queue <- c("James", "Mary", "Steve", "Alex", "Patricia")
queue

# 2.move Patricia to be in front of Steve

???
```

I am a beginner at R so make your responses as simple and watered down as possible! Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any searching?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, you should mention it in the post.

Comment: You should at least [look through the surprisingly well-written manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Introduction-and-preliminaries) before asking questions. For your question, refer to section 2.7. I'd recommend showing us things you have tried before asking questions, as questions with no shown attempt or research are rarely well received.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is:

```
queue <- queue[c(1,2,5,3,4)]
```

But that's manual and not very generalizable. Basically, you reorder the vector by saying how to reorder the current indexes.

If you want to sort the queue alphabetically (which does cause Patricia to be in front of Steve):

```
queue <- sort(queue)
```

Comment: At the end of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25735673/1270695), I've presented an alternative that shows how `setdiff` and `append` can be useful here.

Answer (score 16):

My [`moveMe` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/moveMe.R) (in [my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun)) is perfect for this. Once the package is loaded, you can do what you want with:

```
library(SOfun)
queue <- c("James", "Mary", "Steve", "Alex", "Patricia")
moveMe(queue, "Patricia before Steve")
# [1] "James"    "Mary"     "Patricia" "Steve"    "Alex"
```

You can also compound commands by separating them with semicolons:

```
moveMe(queue, "Patricia before Steve; James last")
# [1] "Mary"     "Patricia" "Steve"    "Alex"     "James" 

moveMe(queue, "Patricia before Steve; James last; Mary after Alex")
# [1] "Patricia" "Steve"    "Alex"     "Mary"     "James"
```

---

Options for moving include: "first", "last", "before", and "after".

You can also move multiple values to a position by separating them by commas. For instance, to move "Patricia" and "Alex" before "Mary" (reordered in that order) and then move "Steve" to the start of the queue, you would use:

```
moveMe(queue, "Patricia, Alex before Mary; Steve first")
# [1] "Steve"    "James"    "Patricia" "Alex"     "Mary"
```

---

You can install SOfun with:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("SOfun", "mrdwab")
```

---

For a single value, moved before another value, you could also take an approach like the following:

```
## Create a vector without "Patricia"
x <- setdiff(queue, "Patricia")
## Use `match` to find the point at which to insert "Patricia"
## Use `append` to insert "Patricia" at the relevant point
x <- append(x, values = "Patricia", after = match("Steve", x) - 1)
x
# [1] "James"    "Mary"     "Patricia" "Steve"    "Alex"
```

Comment: "*Destined to be the most important R package you have ever loaded in your R session.*" - love it.

Comment: @thelatemail, ain't it the truth :-)

Comment: moveMe sounds like a great tool! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: nesting `append(setfiff` solved my problem.

Answer (score -4):

I think you intend for this to be more elegant, but your question doesn't specify how. For simplicity though, just rewrite the definition of `queue`.

```
queue <- c("James", "Mary", "Patricia", "Steve", "Alex")
```